# How to receive data after initiating TCP connection close?

Tags: .net, tcp

TCP allows one side to issue a "FIN", and have the other side respond with some data before ending its side of the connection.

How can I achieve this using .NET's `TcpClient`? It appears that I must use `Close` to issue a FIN, but after that I can no longer call `Client.Receive` since `Client` is set to `null` by `Close`.

Comment: This is supported. You can use Socket directly to do this. I don't know about TcpClient, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this in .NET is to call

```
Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
```

or, if you're using a `TcpClient`:

```
TcpClient.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue a shutdown for output. That sends the FIN and stops you writing anything else but it leaves the other half of the connection open.

Comment: How do I "issue a shutdown for output"?

Comment: @romkyns In C# I have no idea but it will be a method on the socket.